# Send Json Payload to MPNS by AWS SNS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-sns, aws-sdk, mpns

I want to send a json payload to Windows phone 7+ in push notification. I am using **MPNS**.
I am using **AWS SNS** service for sending push notification. IF i am sending a String payload .Everything works for string payload. I got stuck with **Json payload**.

```
paylaod = {default: "None", MPNS:  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><wp:Notification xmlns=\"WPNotification\"><wp:Toast><wp:Text1>SNS Test Message</wp:Text1></wp:Toast></wp:Notification>"}

resp = SNS.publish( target_arn: "arn:aws:sns:usXXXb64", message: paylaod.to_json,  message_structure: 'json')
```

Comment: `message_structure: 'json'` does *not* mean "my payload is JSON."  If you are setting that because your payload is JSON, don't do that.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i can not set it as string . In string case the toast will show  up all the information to the user. This information in notification need to show partially and other part will be used by the app internally

Answer (score 1):

I'm awfully unfamiliar with the Ruby language, but it seems to me that your call lacks message attributes, which are mandatory for JSON-based MPNS messages.

The two attributes are as follows:

For reference, the attributes are the following:

1. Attribute name: `AWS.SNS.MOBILE.MPNS.Type`
   Type: string
   Possible values: `token` (for *tile* notifications), `toast` or `raw`
2. Attribute name: `AWS.SNS.MOBILE.MPNS.NotificationClass`
   Type: string
   Possible values: `realtime`*, `priority`, `regular`
   (realtime worked for me with the Java SDK)

So your last line should look like this:

```
resp = SNS.publish(
    target_arn: "arn:aws:sns:usXXXb64",
    message: paylaod.to_json,
    message_structure: 'json',
    message_attributes: {
        "AWS.SNS.MOBILE.MPNS.Type" => {
            data_type: "String",
            string_value: "toast"
        },
        "AWS.SNS.MOBILE.MPNS.NotificationClass" => {
            data_type: "String",
            string_value: "realtime"
        }
    })
```

---

Note that the `message_structure: 'json'` line is equally important.

Comment: yeah i figured out that too. But have one more issue that toast are not coming when app is closed if device is 8.1 or higher